# Hugo NextInSection with counter

Tags: hugo

I need to accomplish a layout with a link to next and previous post and a counter marking the actual post, bad representation ahead:

`<previousPost 10/100 nextPost>`

I put everything to work, except the mention of the current post number:

```
{{ $posts := (where .Site.RegularPages "Section" "==" "news") }}
{{ $postCount := len $posts }}
{{ $postCount }}

{{ if .PrevInSection }}
  <a href="{{.PrevInSection.Permalink}}">Prev Post</a>
{{ end }}

{{ I have no idea }}/{{ $postCount }}

{{ if .NextInSection }}
  <a href="{{.NextInSection.Permalink}}">Next Post</a>
{{ end }}
```

But I have no clue on how to find the value of the page in the `netxInSection` context. I'm thinking about changing my code to a `range` and use the `index` to mark the current page but I think that should be a smarter way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some head banging on the wall I found a way to do it...

```
      {{ range $index, $element := (where .Site.RegularPages "Type" "news" ).Reverse }}
        {{ if eq . $ }}
          {{- $.Scratch.Set "currentItem" (add $index 1) }}
        {{ end }}
      {{end}}

      {{ $posts := (where .Site.RegularPages "Section" "==" "news") }}
      {{ $postCount := len $posts }}

      {{ if .PrevInSection }}
        <a href="{{.PrevInSection.Permalink}}" class="page-navigation__prev">prev</a>
      {{ else }}
        <a href="" disabled class="page-navigation__prev">prev</a>
      {{ end }}

      <div class="page-navigation__counter">
        {{ $.Scratch.Get "currentItem" }}/{{ $postCount }}
      </div>

      {{ if .NextInSection }}
        <a href="{{.NextInSection.Permalink}}" class="page-navigation__next">next</a>
      {{ else }}
        <a href="" disabled class="page-navigation__next">next</a>
      {{ end }}
```